# how to set proper ramp-up time in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter, I want to create a report, I have following doubts:

1. I want to find out the maximum number of users that can be given in a thread for ramp-up time 1sec?

`Ex: 5 simple Http Request
    no of user : ?
    Ramp up time = 1
    Loop=1`

1. How to set a proper ramp-up time depending on the number of user in a thread?

`Ex: 5 simple Http Request
    no of user : 100
    Ramp up time = ?
    Loop=1`

I tried different combinations of ramp-up and number of users considering through put , but the results varies and not able to find out a relation with the ramp-up time and the number of users.

Please help to find a solution for it.

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on your application & requirement. Usually i do Ramp up period >= No of users

Comment: @Chetan:thanks chetan

Comment: @vIns:but i want to know the load that can be handled by the server in one second.My application contains simple static pages

Comment: @Chetan shared site link is not reachable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ramp-up period is the time required for all threads representing virtual users to start.

JMeter starts with 1 user and kicks off another thread so all threads will start in ramp-up period time slot i.e.

- 10 users, 10 seconds ramp-up - start with 1 user, each second 1 user added
- 10 users, 20 seconds ramp-up - start with 1 user, each 2 seconds 1 user added
- 100 users, 50 seconds ramp-up - start with 1 user, each second 2 users added

Keep in mind that if the thread has finished its job and there are no loops defined it'll **shut down**. For JMeter greenhorns it's better to use [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) (available via plugin) which provides easy-understandable and configurable load pattern definition.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you can also use the following test elements:

- [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - to hold the threads until specified number will be reached and release them at the same moment
- [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - to specify exact load in requests-per-second.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :I tried Constant throughput timer and calculated ramp-up time by (no.of users/throughput).thank you so much for the info